# ERRORnon-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

estoy implementando una clase que me permita crear una lista enlazada. Pero al momento de instanciar a una nueva lista enlazada me salta este error:

> MainListaEnlazada.java:19: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
>                   ListaEnlazada lista = new ListaEnlazada();

¿Alguien podría explicarme qué he hecho mal?

```
    public class MainListaEnlazada {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListaEnlazada lista = new ListaEnlazada();

    }

    class Nodo {
        private Object valor;
        private Nodo siguiente;

        public Nodo(Object valor){
            this.valor = valor;
            this.siguiente = null;
        }

        public void enlazarSiguiente(Nodo n) {
            this.siguiente = n;
        }

        public Object getValor(){
            return valor;
        }

        public Nodo getSiguiente() {
            return siguiente;
        }

    }

    class ListaEnlazada {
        private Nodo cabeza;
        private int size;

        ListaEnlazada(){
            cabeza = null;
            size = 0;
        }

        public void prepend(Object _element) {
            if(cabeza == null){
                cabeza = new Nodo(_element);
            } else {
                Nodo temp = cabeza;
                Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(_element);
                nuevo.enlazarSiguiente(temp);
                cabeza = nuevo;
            }

            this.size++;
        }

        public boolean vacia(){
            return (cabeza == null)?true:false;
        }

        public int size(){
            return this.size;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa por qué estás usando clases internas, lo que tienes que hacer es escribir las clases internas de la siguiente forma:

```
public static class Nombre_Clase_Interna {

....

}
```

En tu caso quedaría así:

```
public class MainListaEnlazada {
public static void main(String[] args){
    ListaEnlazada lista = new ListaEnlazada();

}

static class Nodo {
    private Object valor;
    private Nodo siguiente;

    public Nodo(Object valor){
        this.valor = valor;
        this.siguiente = null;
    }

    public void enlazarSiguiente(Nodo n) {
        this.siguiente = n;
    }

    public Object getValor(){
        return valor;
    }

    public Nodo getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

}

static class ListaEnlazada {
    private Nodo cabeza;
    private int size;

    ListaEnlazada(){
        cabeza = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void prepend(Object _element) {
        if(cabeza == null){
            cabeza = new Nodo(_element);
        } else {
            Nodo temp = cabeza;
            Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(_element);
            nuevo.enlazarSiguiente(temp);
            cabeza = nuevo;
        }

        this.size++;
    }

    public boolean vacia(){
        return (cabeza == null)?true:false;
    }

    public int size(){
        return this.size;
    }
    }
}
```

Otra alternativa para solucionar tu problema es colocar cada clase dentro de su propio archivo, en este caso ya no sería necesario poner clases estáticas.