# guardar el nombre de un jugador y su dinero en un objeto da error non static variable this cannot be referenced

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tengo que guardar el nombre de un jugador y su dinero en un objeto. El problema es que no sé manejar bien Java y al declarar el objeto me sale error.

Tiene que ser un error simple, pero no consigo encontrarlo y he estado revisando cómo se declaraban los objetos en Java y juraría que es justo como lo pongo yo, por favor ayuda.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Adrian
 */
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    class DatosJugador
    {
        protected String nombre = "";
        protected int dinero = 0;

        DatosJugador() {}

        DatosJugador(String nombre, int dinero)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.dinero = dinero;
        }

        public int getDinero()
        {
            return dinero;
        }

        public String getNombre()
        {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setDinero(int newDinero)
        {
            dinero = newDinero;
        }

        public void setNombre(String newNombre)
        {
            nombre = newNombre;
        }

        public String toCSV()
        {
            return nombre + ";" + dinero + ";";
        }

        public void ofCSV(String cadena)
        {
            String[] parts = cadena.split(";");
            nombre = parts[0]; // 123
            dinero = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // 654321
        }
    };
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        DatosJugador j2 = new DatosJugador();
        System.out.println(j2.getNombre() + " y " + j2.getDinero());
    }

}
```

El  error me aparece antes y después de compilarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tipo de error te aparece ? que es lo que deseas hacer con el objeto creado? el problema es al llamarlo en la clase principal o simplemente te da error al compilarlo?

Comment: lo he editado, ahora aparece el error del main

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ERRORnon-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113253/errornon-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es porque el método es static. Los atributos o métodos, que son declarados como estáticos, son como elementos que le pertenecen a la clase y no a la instancia de la clase. O sea, los elementos estáticos son globales para la clase que está cargada en memoria. Como estos elementos pertenecen a la clase y no a la instancia, un atributo o método no estático no se puede llamar desde un método estático.

Recuerda que el Main es el punto de entrada de cualquier programa JAVA, por lo cual, te recomendaría que declares las clases de negocio o entidad fuera de la clase Main. Si creas una nueva clase fuera de la clase Main, tu error se va a solucionar.

Answer (score 4):

El error que te aparece es porque estás intentando instanciar una clase (`DatosJugador`) anidada en otra (`Main`) sin una referencia (objeto) de la clase que contiene a la anidada, `DatosJugador`.

Es decir, tu clase `Main` contiene a la clase `DatosJugador`. Y un objeto de la clase `Main` es el que puede instanciar la clase `DatosJugador`, porque la clase, y el constructor son parte de `Main`.

Se solucionaría si agregas la línea:

```
DatosJugador j2 = new Main().new DatosJugador();
```

También se solucionaría si declaras `DatosJugador` como clase estática, con lo que estás queriendo decir que la clase anidada no pertenece a las instancias de `Main`, sino a la clase en sí misma. Y podrías escribir algo como.

```
static class DatosJugador { ... }
DatosJugador j2 = Main.new DatosJugador();
```

Y teniendo en cuenta que estás dentro de la clase `Main`, puedes omitir la referencia a la clase porque se sobre entiende.

```
static class DatosJugador { ... }
DatosJugador j2 = new DatosJugador();  // Se sobre entiene la referencia Main
```

Así que cuidado con anidar clases. Si bien es totalmente legal en Java, no es lo más recomendable. En general cada clase debería ser declarada en un fichero. Y este es un claro ejemplo de por qué.

También, si va a anidar clases, ten en cuenta que un buen diseño es anidar clases que están relacionadas con la clase que las contiene (como anidar una clase `Nodo` en una clase `Lista`). Anidar sin motivo suele ser el resultado de un mal diseño. Por lo que te recomendaría que definas la clase `DatosJugador` en un fichero aparte.

**Puntualización:**

Como comenta Franco Torres en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395527/problema-al-declarar-objeto-en-java/395534#395534), el error que comento yo es visible porque intentas instanciar `DatosJugador` dentro de un método estático de `Main`.

En un método de instancia (no estático), siempre habrá una referencia al objeto que está ejecutando el método, mediante la palabra clave `this`. Así, cuando haces algo como `j2.getNombre();`, es `j2` quien va a ejecutar el método `getNombre()`, y por tanto, dentro del código de `getNombre()`, `this` hará referencia a `j2`, que es instancia de `DatosJugador`.

En cambio, en un método estático no existe un `this` al uso, porque no es ningún objeto quien ejecuta dicho método. El método estático le pertenece a la clase, y es la propia clase la que lo ejecuta.

Con esto en mente, al escribir `new DatosJugador()` dentro de un método cualquiera de la clase `Main`:

- Si el método es de instancia: se sobre entiende `this`, por lo que puedes crear instancias de `DatosJugador` con la sentecia `new DatosJugador()`, que es equivalente a escribir `this.new DatosJugador()`.
- Si el método es estático: la referencia `this` no existe, por lo que hay que crear un objeto `Main` para que el objeto creado ejecute el constructor de `DatosJugador` mediante la sentencia `new Main().new Jugador();`.
- En cualquier caso, hace falta una referencia a algún objeto de la clase `Main`.